# Excel VBA IF ElseIf

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement

I keep on getting a 'mismatched type error', or some other menial error like 'no block if'. However when I fix one, the other pops back up. Not sure where the problem is in this code. It's pretty straight forward, get cell values and then classify based on the values.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Dim sh1 As Worksheet
Dim sh2 As Worksheet
Set sh1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Completed Questionnaire")
Set sh2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Classifier")

If sh1.Range("C10") = "Yes" Or sh1.Range("C11") = "Yes" Then
    If sh1.Range("C19:C20") = "Yes" Or sh1.Range("C17") = "Yes" Then
        sh2.Unprotect Password:="xxx"
        sh2.Range("D4") = "PS1"
        sh2.Protect Password:="xxx"
    End If

ElseIf sh1.Range("C10") = "Yes" Or sh1.Range("C11") = "Yes" And _
    sh1.Range("C14") = "Yes" Or _
    sh1.Range("C15") = "Yes" Or _
    sh1.Range("C16") = "Yes" Or _
    sh1.Range("C18") = "Yes" Then
        sh2.Unprotect Password:="xxx"
        sh2.Range("D4") = "PS2"
        sh2.Protect Password:="xxx"

ElseIf sh1.Range("C12") = "Yes" And sh1.Range("C21") = "Yes" Then
    If sh1.Range("C10:C11") = "No" Then
        sh2.Unprotect Password:="xxx"
        sh2.Range("D4") = "PS3"
        sh2.Protect Password:="xxx"
    End If


ElseIf sh1.Range("C13") = "Vendor Only" And sh1.Range("C10:C11") = "Yes" 
Then _ 
    If ("C14") = "Yes" Or _
    sh1.Range("C15") = "Yes" Or _
    sh1.Range("C16") = "Yes" Or _
    sh1.Range("C17") = "Yes" Or _
    sh1.Range("C18") = "Yes" Or _
    sh1.Range("C19") = "Yes" Or _
    sh1.Range("C20") = "Yes" Then _
        sh2.Unprotect Password:="xxx"
        sh2.Range("D4") = "Payment Process"
        sh2.Protect Password:="xxx"
    End If

ElseIf sh1.Range("C10:C21") = "No" Then
    sh2.Unprotect Password:="xxx"
    sh2.Range("D4") = "Non-Payment"
    sh2.Protect Password:="xxx"

Else: sh2.Unprotect Password:="xxx"
    sh2.Range("D4") = "Needs Review"
    sh2.Protect Password:="xxx"

End If
Sheets("Classifier").Select

End Sub
```

Comment: look for cells with errors

Comment: Also you have a `Then` on a separate line here - is what SO has *exactly* as you have it in VBA?  Also, try not to use the `Else: ...` and just put that part on a separate line too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Dim sh1     As Worksheet
Dim sh2     As Worksheet
Set sh1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Completed Questionnaire")
Set sh2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Classifier")

If sh1.Range("C10") = "Yes" Or sh1.Range("C11") = "Yes" Then
    If sh1.Range("C19:C20") = "Yes" Or sh1.Range("C17") = "Yes" Then
        sh2.Unprotect Password:="xxx"
        sh2.Range("D4") = "PS1"
        sh2.Protect Password:="xxx"
    End If

ElseIf sh1.Range("C10") = "Yes" Or sh1.Range("C11") = "Yes" And _
       sh1.Range("C14") = "Yes" Or _
       sh1.Range("C15") = "Yes" Or _
       sh1.Range("C16") = "Yes" Or _
       sh1.Range("C18") = "Yes" Then
        sh2.Unprotect Password:="xxx"
        sh2.Range("D4") = "PS2"
        sh2.Protect Password:="xxx"

ElseIf sh1.Range("C12") = "Yes" And sh1.Range("C21") = "Yes" Then
    If sh1.Range("C10:C11") = "No" Then
        sh2.Unprotect Password:="xxx"
        sh2.Range("D4") = "PS3"
        sh2.Protect Password:="xxx"
    End If

ElseIf sh1.Range("C13") = "Vendor Only" And sh1.Range("C10:C11") = "Yes" Then
    If ("C14") = "Yes" Or _
       sh1.Range("C15") = "Yes" Or _
       sh1.Range("C16") = "Yes" Or _
       sh1.Range("C17") = "Yes" Or _
       sh1.Range("C18") = "Yes" Or _
       sh1.Range("C19") = "Yes" Or _
       sh1.Range("C20") = "Yes" Then
        sh2.Unprotect Password:="xxx"
        sh2.Range("D4") = "Payment Process"
        sh2.Protect Password:="xxx"
    End If

ElseIf sh1.Range("C10:C21") = "No" Then
    sh2.Unprotect Password:="xxx"
    sh2.Range("D4") = "Non-Payment"
    sh2.Protect Password:="xxx"
Else
    sh2.Unprotect Password:="xxx"
    sh2.Range("D4") = "Needs Review"
    sh2.Protect Password:="xxx"
End If
Sheets("Classifier").Select

End Sub
```

I fixed a few errant newlines and mixed `_`.  Note, there's a better way to do your various `Or` statements. But first, can all those cells be `Yes`, or only one at a time, for you to want to unprotect and protect?

Edit: I *think* I cleaned it up a little, using `COUNTIF()`.  See if this works:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Dim sh1     As Worksheet
Dim sh2     As Worksheet
Set sh1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Completed Questionnaire")
Set sh2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Classifier")

If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(sh1.Range("C10:C11", "C14"), "Yes") > 0 Then
    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(sh1.Range("C19:C20", "C17"), "Yes") > 0 Then
        sh2.Unprotect Password:="xxx"
        sh2.Range("D4") = "PS1"
        sh2.Protect Password:="xxx"
    End If

ElseIf WorksheetFunction.CountIf(sh1.Range("C10:C11"), "Yes") > 0 And _
       WorksheetFunction.CountIf(sh1.Range("C14:C16", "C18"), "Yes") > 0 Then
    sh2.Unprotect Password:="xxx"
    sh2.Range("D4") = "PS2"
    sh2.Protect Password:="xxx"

ElseIf WorksheetFunction.CountIf(sh1.Range("C12, C21"), "Yes") > 0 Then
    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(sh1.Range("C10:C11"), "No") > 0 Then
        sh2.Unprotect Password:="xxx"
        sh2.Range("D4") = "PS3"
        sh2.Protect Password:="xxx"
    End If

ElseIf sh1.Range("C13") = "Vendor Only" And WorksheetFunction.CountIf(sh1.Range("C10:C11"), "Yes") > 0 Then
    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(sh1.Range("C14:C20"), "Yes") > 0 Then
        sh2.Unprotect Password:="xxx"
        sh2.Range("D4") = "Payment Process"
        sh2.Protect Password:="xxx"
    End If

ElseIf WorksheetFunction.CountIf(sh1.Range("C10:C21"), "No") > 0 Then
    sh2.Unprotect Password:="xxx"
    sh2.Range("D4") = "Non-Payment"
    sh2.Protect Password:="xxx"
Else
    sh2.Unprotect Password:="xxx"
    sh2.Range("D4") = "Needs Review"
    sh2.Protect Password:="xxx"
End If
Sheets("Classifier").Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Batma... I mean Master Wayne, I'd love to hear how to improve all the Or statements... and all the cells can potentially be "Yes", It doesn't have to be one at a time, I just need to check the contents of each cell, and as long as one of them contains a "Yes" it will execute the unprotect.

Comment: @Mdurocher - See the edited add'l code. I *think* that may help. I don't think it's possible to do `Range("A1:A2") = "Yes"` to see if either (or both) cells in that range are a value.  You should get a `Type Mismatch` error if I'm not mistaken. Therefore I used `Countif()`.

Answer (score 3):

### Comparing multiple cells at once

Comparing multiple cell values to other value is failing, e.g.:
`sh1.Range("C19:C20") = "Yes"`
What are you trying to do here? Test that both C19 AND C20 are = "Yes"?
Then (god forbid me for the code i am to write) use 2 comparisons:
`sh1.Range("C19") = "Yes" AND sh1.Range("C20") = "Yes"`

### Syntax error

There is a syntax error in the 4th main IF block:
`ElseIf sh1.Range("C13") = "Vendor Only" And sh1.Range("C10:C11") = "Yes"
Then _`
Should be:
`ElseIf sh1.Range("C13") = "Vendor Only" And sh1.Range("C10:C11") = "Yes" Then`

And to apply what we learned above, it should really be:
`ElseIf sh1.Range("C13") = "Vendor Only" And sh1.Range("C19") = "Yes" AND sh1.Range("C20") = "Yes" Then`